# <BR> tag not working in .properties file

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a DOJO JavaScript project wherein I am using x.js rendered from the file x.properties virtually. I mean internally .properties is getting converted to a .js

I have key value pairs in it, for example:

x.properties:

> name=pavan
>   class=xyz
>   school=Lions Model school. <br> Primary school.

Something like this. I wanted the primary school to be displayed in a new line.
The output looks something like the following:

> Lions Model school. <br> Primary school.

Instead of newline, i am getting <br> displayed like a string.

What I tried until now is:

1. \n
2. \\n
3. \r\n
4. <br>
5. <br/>

But nothing worked so far, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The property file contains only strings. What you want is to get an html element. Try the simple method `eval()` before you print it out or look for this tag and generate two lines, instead of one.

Comment: Thank you reply. i do understand that .properties files contains only strings. However I am still unable to understand why even "\n" is not working!! Kindly let me know is ther a particular reason to use eval().

Comment: `\n` does not exists under HTML, only in Javascript.

Comment: `eval()` is a simple and powerful method to parse strings to code what the browser can understand.

Comment: Since i am rendering(converting) .properties to .js file , i think '\n' should work.

Comment: Still not recieved correct solution for this.! And by the way I am not printing out .. I am using this label in mouseover property of DOJO.. Please let me know if i am understanding it in a wrong way.

Comment: Then please add source code or better an example link to jsfiddle and show us what you do. You can do this by using the edit button underneath your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve this issue by replace function..

> Replaced `&lt;`  with `<` 
>  Replaced `&gt;` with `>`

Working fine now... Thanks for the inputs